# How can i store API Keys or API Paths on Github Actions to make Expo read it on Build?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am currently building expo ios and android locally, but now i am going to use github actions to build it automatically, but when i do, My expo build doesnt read the env, where can i store and secure .env files to make my expo builds have it again?

Comment: you either remove the .env from .gitignore or create a new one

Comment: Hello, i fixed it by adding env: in my github actions and adding github secrets